# Form of being+v3

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

1. We managed to climb over the wall without ***being seen.***
2. We managed to climb over the wall without ***we were being seen.***

Are these sentences exactly the same? if so is there any special name for the reduction in the first sentence? Is it present or past participle clause? I am so confused.

Comment: #2 makes no sense.  #1 is the only correct way to say it.  I don't know if there is a name for the "reduction" in it, since it isn't really a reduction of anything else.

Comment: Okey , if we use while instead of without for instances : "We managed to climb over the wall while not being seen" or "We managed to climb over the wall while we were not being seen".

Comment: "...while not being seen" is OK.  "...while we were not being seen" seems technically grammatically correct, but it also sounds very clumsy and non-fluent.

Comment: By the way, **being** is only ever the present participle of *to be*.  The past participle of *to be* is **been**.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is correct and idiomatic.

Your second is not. **Without** is a preposition. You can't follow it with **I** or **we** which are used to form the subjects of sentences. You would have to say: **without our being seen** but the **our** is unnecessary. It adds nothing to the meaning.

Other options are:

> We managed to climb over the wall without anyone seeing us.

and

> We managed to climb over the wall without having been seen.

and

> We managed to climb over the wall without alerting anyone.

But none of these improves your first example.